# How to occupy 100% of the height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a navbar but I have a responsive problem when trying to occupy 100% of the height of the screen.

any solution? thanks to all

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96fadf0e69.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <img class="navbar__logo" src="gamezonia.png" alt="logo" />

      <ul class="navbar__list">
        <li class="list__item">Inicio</li>
        <li class="list__item">Categoria 1</li>
        <li class="list__item">Categoria 2</li>
        <li class="list__item">Categoria 3</li>
        <li class="list__item">Contacto</li>
        <li class="list__item">Acceder</li>
        <li class="list__item--search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="navbar__hamburger">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.navbar{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #2B2F33;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


.navbar__logo{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar__list{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.list__item{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.list__item--search{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.navbar__hamburger{
    display: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    align-self: center;
}

@media (max-width: 850px){

    .navbar{
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar__list{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 30%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #2B2F33;
        top: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s;
    }

    .navbar__hamburger{
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .showMenu{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    .list__item, .list__item--search{
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
}
```

JS:

```
console.log('works')

document.querySelector('.navbar__hamburger').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.querySelector('.navbar__list').classList.toggle('showMenu')
})
```

Comment: give the navbar a `height: 100vh` - margins. alternativly you can use a position attribute with `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`

Comment: has height: 100vh property in media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it seems like that navbar is scrolled up (the first four `li`s at the top are missing or not visible), so I would guess its container (`nav`) is *higher*  than the screen and scrolls, or the navbar is somehow moved up under the top border of the screen.

A simple solution would be to change `position` from `absolute` to `fixed`, the the 100vh high navbar would remain in position and not scroll. You might have to adjust some other settings, but I supposse that should work.

Comment: it works !, but I have a new problem xD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885110/why-arent-all-the-items-in-my-ul-displayed?noredirect=1#comment114717675_64885110

Answer (score 1):

Since the sidenav is inside the `<nav>` you can't use `height: 100%`. What you could do is combine `position: fixed` and `height: 100vh` like this:

```
.navbar__list {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #2B2F33;
    top: 0px;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

It will still need some changes in order to keep the sidenav under the nav but it's a good start.