# Why aren't all the items in my ul displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive navbar, but not all the items from my ul are showing,

PROBLEM:

[image]

```js
    console.log('works')
    
    document.querySelector('.container__hamburger').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        document.querySelector('.container__navbar').classList.toggle('showMenu')
    })
```

```css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
    
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #2b2f33;
      width: 100%;
      height: 65px;
    }
    
    .container__navbar {
      display: flex;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .container__logo {
      display: inline;
      width: 25%;
      margin-right: 30px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .navbar__list {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;
      align-items: center;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .list__item{
      margin-right: 30px;
    }
    
    
    .container__hamburger {
      display: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      align-self: center;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 890px) {
    
      .container {
        position: fixed;
      }
    
      .container__navbar {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 65px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        background-color: #2b2f33;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        width: 250px;
      }
    
      .showMenu {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    
      .navbar__list {
        display: block;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    
      .container__hamburger {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }
    
      .list__item {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <img
            class="container__logo"
            src="assets/images/gamezonia.png"
            alt="logo"
          />
          <nav class="container__navbar">
            <ul class="navbar__list">
              <li class="list__item">Home</li>
              <li class="list__item">Category 1</li>
              <li class="list__item">Category 2</li>
              <li class="list__item">Category 3</li>
              <li class="list__item">Contact</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item2</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item3</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item4</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item5</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item6</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    
          <div class="container__hamburger">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
        <script
          src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96fadf0e69.js"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: pack your code in a fiddle or codepen so it's testable

Comment: @EugenSunic We discourage links to 3rd party sites. Executable code can be embedded right here in the question.

Comment: it's hard to test those things within an iframe.. such cases should permit a third party other than that I agree

Comment: I see all the items. Can't reproduce.

Comment: @EugenSunic What are "those things" and where is the `iframe`? As you can see, I've updated the question to have executable code and it works just fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yep, You can see all the items if the bar is on the right, but if it is below you only see 4, it depends on the height (by the bar I mean the developer tool )

Comment: Well of course if the window isn't big enough to see all the items, you won't see them all, but the scroll bar allows you to scroll to see the ones that are out of view.

Comment: Can you see all  elements when scrolling is enabled?

Comment: No, but I have a scrollbar that I can use to see the ones that are out of view.

Comment: what ?, I can only see up to "item 4", using the scrollbar (look the photo of the post)

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I can see the issue too in Chrome and FF. I get the scroll bar but cant scroll past Item 4. Apparent in the snippet without expanding to full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've dropped the `.container__navbar` down the viewport by 65 pixels. You need to take this off the 100% height using `height:calc(100% - 65px);`

```js
console.log('works')
    
    document.querySelector('.container__hamburger').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        document.querySelector('.container__navbar').classList.toggle('showMenu')
    })
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
    
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #2b2f33;
      width: 100%;
      height: 65px;
    }
    
    .container__navbar {
      display: flex;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .container__logo {
      display: inline;
      width: 25%;
      margin-right: 30px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .navbar__list {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;
      align-items: center;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .list__item{
      margin-right: 30px;
    }
    
    
    .container__hamburger {
      display: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      align-self: center;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 890px) {
    
      .container {
        position: fixed;
      }
    
      .container__navbar {
        position: fixed;
        height: calc(100% - 65px);
        left: 0;
        top: 65px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        background-color: #2b2f33;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        width: 250px;
      }
    
      .showMenu {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    
      .navbar__list {
        display: block;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    
      .container__hamburger {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }
    
      .list__item {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <img
            class="container__logo"
            src="assets/images/gamezonia.png"
            alt="logo"
          />
          <nav class="container__navbar">
            <ul class="navbar__list">
              <li class="list__item">Home</li>
              <li class="list__item">Category 1</li>
              <li class="list__item">Category 2</li>
              <li class="list__item">Category 3</li>
              <li class="list__item">Contact</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item2</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item3</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item4</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item5</li>
              <li class="list__item">Item6</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    
          <div class="container__hamburger">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
        <script
          src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96fadf0e69.js"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```